# how control value of variable during run time

Tags: vb.net, variables, controls

How can i control variable value during run time? I want control the variable value that if it larger than 10 project stop the run.
The my variable repeat in my project and i myself do not check it. I want the project itself control it.
How can i do it?
like this
this sub or ... control my variable.

```
sub or  ... control_ypos()
      if ypos>10 then
           exit environment
      end if
end sub
sub main()
  for i=0 to myarray1.length-1
      ypos +=i
  next
  for i=0 to myarray2.length-1
      ypos +=i
  next
....
end sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Exit Environment`, use `End` to stop close the entire program. If you just want to exit the sub, use `Exit Sub`. If you want to exit a `For .. Next` loop, `Exit For`

Comment: thank you for reply....But my problem is not exit environment or like this...my problem is check variable value automatically during run time.

Comment: OK. Which variable and do you want it checked at fixed intervals or at certain points during code execution?

Comment: Variable value change frequently during run and it has not certain point.

Comment: I want to know that project can check variable value automatically or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK The only way I can think of is to create a class which raises an event if a number is outside the range defined when an instance is created.

Ok this is the class have a look at the comments to see how it works.

```
Friend Class MonitoredNumber(Of t As IComparable)
    ' Using of T means that the variable can be any type - Integer, Single, Double etc
    Private MonitoredValue As t
    Private _minValue As t
    Private _maxValue As t

    'this creates a an event handler
    Public Event OutOfRange()

    'this is the constructor that you will use when you create the "Variable" even though it is actually an instance of the MonitoredNumber class
    'and it defines the minimum and maximum values
    Public Sub New(min As t, max As t)
        _minValue = min
        _maxValue = max
    End Sub

    Public Property Value As t
        Get
            Return MonitoredValue
        End Get
        Set(value As t)
            MonitoredValue = value
            'if the "variable is set to a value outside the defined range, then the OutOfRangeEvent is raised
            If MonitoredValue.CompareTo(_minValue) < 0 Or MonitoredValue.CompareTo(_maxValue) > 0 Then
                RaiseEvent OutOfRange()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

To create the "variable" add this to your code where you defined the variable that you want to monitor - naming it how you like of course

```
Dim WithEvents x As New MonitoredNumber(Of Integer)(4, 5)
```

In the above line the keyword `WithEvents` makes sure that the OutOfRange event is handled by the event handler below.

`Of Integer` should be changed to what type of number you want to keep track of. If it's a Double then change it to `Of Double` etc.

The two parameters are the minimum and maximum acceptable values for the number - changed these to whatever you need.

In your form you finally need to add the event handler below for the `OutOfRange` event.

```
Private Sub MonitoredNumberChanged() Handles x.OutOfRange
    'do stuff here to do what you want to do if the event is out of range
    MessageBox.Show("Value out of range. Value =" & x.Value.ToString)
End Sub
```

So to use your code, define ypos as

```
Dim WithEvents ypos As New MonitoredNumber(Of Integer)(0, 10)
```

I'm presuming 0 as the minimum value here, but you can change it to whatever you like.

Then, in your event handler, you can write the code that you want to execute when the number is out of range.

To change the value of the number, use
ypos.value=ypos.value+1 'to add one to it and so on

Hope this points you in the right direction. If you're declaring more than one instance of the MonitoredNumberClass, you should create another event handler for that instance of course.

If any other user has a better way, please feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: Thank you...I think this is better and is my answer

Comment: It would probably be even a better idea to use an abstract lambda predicate instead of min/max values, and, if conventional, overload the default constructor. This also raises the limitation of requiring a type to implement IComparable.
See: pastebin.com/dPbj4Kws

Answer (score 1):

*Please correct me if I'm wrong; I don't have Visual Studio at hand right now so I write from memory. It is possible there are some syntax errors, but the principle itself should be right.*

If you aren't planning on creating such control variables at runtime, you could just create a property in some dummy module:

```
Module Dummy
    Dim _ypos As Integer = 0
    Public Property control_ypos As Integer
        Get
            Return _ypos
        End Get
        Set
            If _ypos>10 Then 'Do the checking stuff
                End
            Else
                _ypos = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Module

Sub Main()
    For I=0 To myarray1.Length-1
        Dummy.control_ypos += I
    Next
    For I=0 to myarray2.Length-1
        Dummy.control_ypos += I
    Next
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: @MDA, glad it helped, even if not as good as the other one. Please, note that here, on StackOverflow, it is frowned upon to make a comments like "Thanks!", "+1", "Me too!" and the like. If you feel this answer is useful, just upvote it. :)

Comment: yes you are right but i do not allow give vote your answer because my reputation is less than 15.